# Error while installing records library via pip for Python

Tags: python, pip, records

just found this [records library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/records/) (version 0.5.0) for Python (my version is 3.6.0) and tried to install it with

```
$ pip3 install records
```

The package loads and finishes but afterwards the installation is quitting with this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/
```

The rest of the log says:

```
  Using cached tablib-0.11.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        import tablib
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from tablib.core import (
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/core.py", line 15, in <module>
        from tablib import formats
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/formats/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import _csv as csv
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/formats/_csv.py", line 6, in <module>
        from tablib.compat import is_py3, csv, StringIO
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/compat.py", line 25, in <module>
        import tablib.packages.xlwt3 as xlwt
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/packages/xlwt3/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .Row import Row
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/packages/xlwt3/Row.py", line 7, in <module>
        from . import ExcelFormula
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/packages/xlwt3/ExcelFormula.py", line 1, in <module>
        from . import ExcelFormulaParser, ExcelFormulaLexer
      File "/tmp/pip-build-cgungwv4/tablib/tablib/packages/xlwt3/ExcelFormulaLexer.py", line 52, in <module>
        VERBOSE+LOCALE+IGNORECASE)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
        return _compile(pattern, flags)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
        p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
        p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 866, in parse
        p.pattern.flags = fix_flags(str, p.pattern.flags)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 833, in fix_flags
        raise ValueError("cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern")
    ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks upfront :)

Comment: A [bug in tablib](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/267) apparently.  You can ait for them to fix, or install from master branch if you are comfortable with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the issue in tablib: https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/issues/267

Your options:

1) wait until they fix the pip version

2) install it yourself from the master branch which seems to have been fixed

Comment: Ended up using
`$ pip3 install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib.git`
and then continuing with the usual installation routine
`$ pip3 install records`
Now everything works. Thanks for your help everyone :)